# Migrating to Springboot3, JDK17, Gradle7.5.1, and Tomcat10, Tomcat won't launch my web app

Tags: java-17, tomcat10, spring-boot-3

My webapp works with Springboot 2.7x, JDK8, Tomcat9, and Gradle 7.4x.  I converted everything to Springboot3, JDK17, Tomcat10, and Gradle7.5.1, and am able to build the war file without any issues.  While trying to launch tomcat (outside of the embedded one, don't ask, that's how they want to do it), I get a stack trace (that I am not able to paste here for technical reasons) that ends with:

SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive [path to tomcat/webapps/project]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child

...

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifeCycleException: Failed to start component [X509JAASRealm[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[hostname].StandardContext[/project]]]

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because the return value of "javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getAppConfigurationEntry(String) is null

My code does not call that method so I don't know where it resides.  Is it possible I am missing a dependency jar that I need to add to my build.gradle file?  Has anyone run into this exact problem?  Does anyone know the jar that THAT method lives in?

I have searched on google for an answer but can't find this exact problem.  I have tweaked and tweaked but nothing is working.  I don't believe it is my code because everything works with Springboot 2.7.4, and outside version of Tomcat9.  I simply don't know what else to try.

Comment: I solved this by adding missing properties to my catalina.properties file.